# Android: Action_Send return Extra_Stream: How to get the extension of the file

Tags: android, action, send, file-extension

Is there a way to extract the extension of the content: uri returned from Action_Send.

I can open the stream to the the content given by the Extra_Stream when Action_Send was received but I need to name the file with proper extension of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to name the file with proper extension of the file

It's not a file. It's a piece of content.

For example, what is the "proper extension" of this Web page? Its URL is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558630/android-action-send-return-extra-stream-how-to-get-the-extension-of-the-file`.

A `Uri` works the same way. It is an opaque handle to some content. Do not assume that it has a file extension.

You *can* get the MIME type, via `DocumentFile`. From there, `MimeTypeMap` may be able to suggest a file extension that you can use.

Comment: Cool I can get the name of the file too. Thank you so much

Comment: @LittleFunny: You can get a display name of the content. Whether this resembles a filename is up to the provider of that content.

Comment: In that case, I will have to check whether the extension can be extracted if not assume it was an unknown file type. Thank for your help